# Анимация, если блок в зоне видимости

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

не могу решить задачу воспроизведения разовой анимации при скроле. Находил пример, только когда блок полностью в зоне видимости. Но надо как только он появляется в зоне видимости.
Вот небольшой код:

```
$(".load-marker").addClass('load-not-active');
var $win = $(window);
var $marker = $('.load-marker');
$win.scroll(function() {
    $marker.each(function() {
        if ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() >= $( this ).offset().top &&) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

но анимация у меня при этом срабатывает и для всех блоков выше текущего. То есть если пользователь обновит страницу и скролл останется по центру страницы, то анимация сработает и для все элементов, что выше его. А надо, чтобы анимация срабатывала только для того, что появляется в зоне видимости.

Comment: Условие должно состоять из двух частей: если верхняя часть блока выше нижней кромки экрана **И** нижняя часть блока ниже верхней кромки экрана.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тебе нужно определить высоту страницы, высоту элементов, высоту прокрутки и отступ элемента от края страницы. Попробуй вот такой код, здесь каждый див будет подсвечиваться только когда он полностью окажется в области видимости:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<style type="text/css">

        div {

            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            margin-right: 100%;
            background: #eee;
            margin-bottom: 10px;

        }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var window_height = (window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : (document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.offsetHeight));

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    var top = document.body.scrollTop;
    var find = false;
    elements.forEach(function(el) {

        var el_top = el.offsetTop;
        if(el_top > top && ((el.clientHeight + el_top) < (top + window_height))) {
            el.style.backgroundColor = "#999";
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: код очень полезный и он точно окажется в моей коллекции, но надо было анимацию запускать сразу как только он начнет показываться. Комментарий к вопросу помог с этой проблемой

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь. Удачи